# Making table from MySQL query with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, query, mysql, query-table

I am trying to interact directly with data from a MySQL database in ArcMap using Python. So far, I have successfully connected the database using the MySQLdb.connect() function and have successfully executed queries using the cur.execute() function. I also am able to print the results in the Python window.

I cannot, however, figure out how to create a table from the query output that I can then use to, for instance, join to a shapefile or display XY data. I assumed that the MakeQueryTable_management() function would allow me to do this, but the syntax is very confusing to me. Do I execute the query using cur.execute() and then execute this function, does this function replace the cur.execute() function, or do I do something altogether different?

for example, here is a query:

```
cur.execute("SELECT count(zip_codes.zip_code) AS Zips, zip_codes.state FROM   zip_codes GROUP BY zip_codes.state ORDER BY zip_codes.state ASC")
```

so how would I write the MakQueryTable_management() function given this syntax?

```
MakeQueryTable_management (in_table, out_table, in_key_field_option, {in_key_field}, {in_field}, {where_clause})
```

I am new to ArcPy.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that we try to keep chit chat (e.g. greetings, thanks, signatures, etc) out of questions and answers (think of them as being a wiki).  For help with code we need you to include a code snippet of what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the exact version of ArcGIS in use, as well as the exact Python code. I suspect you're trying to use two different access libraries that do not work together, and are being too casual in object access methods.

Comment: Please do not re-insert the "chit-chat" that has been removed by policy.

Answer (score 1):

Consulting the [online documentation for Make Query Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-query-table.htm), it states:

> This tool accepts data from an ArcSDE geodatabase, a file geodatabase, a personal geodatabase, or an OLE DB connection.

So your first task is to create an OLE DB connection to MySQL (since MySQL isn't supported in enterprise geodatabases).

I'd recommend making a view in MySQL and just accessing that through OLE DB.