# ArcMap to MySQL using Modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, mysql

Is it possible to run a model in ArcMap 10.3 and export directly to a MySQL table? Preferably avoiding ArcSDE as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect to MySQL using [OLE DB connection](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011488) and then use the connection in your model. If you can, it might be easier to write a [tiny Python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172047/making-table-from-mysql-query-with-arcpy) that you could invoke as part of the model. In the Python script, you would have a more fine-grained control over the table creation as you can use the SQL.

No ArcSDE will be involved whatsoever because ArcGIS doesn't support having MySQL as an enterprise geodatabase.